# How to see pods and other resources in AWS EKS portal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've just started with AWS EKS, did setup kubeconfig and I can list nodes correctly.
I tried to create a simple deployment using below command

```
root@ganesh-virtual-machine:~# kubectl create deployment --image nginx nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created
root@ganesh-virtual-machine:~#
```

However, I dont see any new resources pod/deployment/namespace created using kubectl at the AWS EKS portal. Is there anything I have to do to see these resources ?